# How can you put a bool in a if else statement in Python?

Tags: python, class

```
class Wheels(Car):
    def __init__(self, name, noise, canMakeNoise):
        self.name = name
        self.noise = noise
        self.canMakeNoise = Bool

    def makeNoise(self):
        if canMakeNoise = False:
            Wheels.name + "" + "vroom"
        else: 
            print Wheels.name + "" + "remains silent"
```

If I run that code, I get this error:

```
File "python", line 26
    if canMakeNoise = False:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can you put a bool in a if else statement in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't.  The proper way to do this in Python is:

```
if not canMakeNoise:
```

and:

```
if canMakeNoise:
```

for the opposite.  From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Don't compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==`.
>
> Yes:   `if greeting:`
>   
>   No:   `if greeting == True:`
>   
>   Worse: `if greeting is True:`

---

<sub>Just for the sake of completeness, you need to use `==` for comparisons.   `=` is for assignment.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
def makeNoise(self):
    if canMakeNoise:
        print Wheels.name + "" + "remains silent"
    else: 
        Wheels.name + "" + "vroom"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary if/else, also using `str.format` will make your concatenation a bit nicer:

```
print"{} remains silent".format(Wheels.name) if canmakeNoise else "{} vroom".format(Wheels.name)
```